# getting undefined although variable is declared on socket

Tags: node.js, websocket

This is my server side code

```
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
 socket.username = 'john';
```

this is my client side

```
socket.on("connect", () => {  console.log(socket.username); });
```

but I get undefined. I also tried

```
socket.on("connect", () => {  console.log(username); });
```

but no use, however this here works:

```
socket.on("connect", () => {  console.log(socket.id); });
```

why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Properties you assign to the socket object on the server are NOT sent to the client socket object - they are unique to the server object.

Similarly, if you set a property on the client socket object, it will not be present on the server socket object.

These are different objects that exist in different processes on different computers.  The `socket.id` property is the same on both client and server objects ONLY because the socket.io library sends the id from the server to the client as part of the connection process and the client-side socket.io library initializes that property on the client-size socket object.

If you want properties to be present on both objects, then you will have to send a message from client to server or server to client with the value of that property and then have the other end set that property on its socket object.  This is not something that socket.io does auto-magically for you.

---

To repeat, when you do this on the server-side:

```
socket.username = 'john';
```

That does not affect the client-side socket object at all.  The client and server socket objects are completely different objects running in different processes and usually on different computers communicating over a network.  They do not automatically share any properties except for a few properties that the socket.io library purposely initializes to be the same in each such as the `socket.id` property.

You send data to the other end of the socket using something like this:

```
socket.emit("yourMessageName", yourData);
```

Comment: you mean its absolutely not possible to set values for socket? But how come they go just fine when I send them over  socket.on('new message', msg) or login?

Comment: @snksaint - What do you mean "go just fine".  You can freely send messages over the socket.io connection (that's what it's for), but that has nothing to do with custom properties on the socket object itself.  It appears you may be mixing up the concepts of socket properties and messages sent over the socket connection.

Comment: isnt there anyway then to send data over the client on connect?

Comment: so in this case it would be `io.on('connection', (socket) => { const username = myname; socket.send(msg, data);` on server whereas for the client `socket.on("connect", () => {  console.log(data.username); }); ` is that correct?

Comment: Im trying to send their member data to each user. I got it down now with socket.emit. scoekt.send doesnt seem to do anything on my end.

Comment: @snksaint - Yes, it is `socket.emit()`.

Comment: thanks for your time.